Get Distance between 2 records
Get Distance between 2 records
while creating the record in lead object lead assign automatically near owner base upon zipcode
anyone have Apex logic how to create the logic?
for(Lead ld:[Select Id, City, State, SIC_Code_1__c, Latitude, Longitude from Lead where Id = :CurrentId])
{
    Latitudes = ld.Latitude;
    Longtitudes = ld.Longitude;
}

if(Siccodes !=null && !Siccodes.isEmpty()){
    Temporary.clear();
    for (Opportunity opp:[Select Id, Name, StageName, Account.name, Number_of_Units__c, account.SIC_Code__c, Type,
                          Billing_City__c, Billing_State_Province__c, account.SIC_Industry_Name__c,
                          account.No_of_active_units__c, account.BillingLatitude, account.BillingLongitude from opportunity where account.SIC_Code__c 
                          LIKE :codes and StageName = 'Closed Won' ORDER BY account.No_of_active_units__c Desc NULLS LAST Limit 10])
    {
        if(opp.account.SIC_Code__c <> null)
        {
            Temporary.add(opp);
            Total = DISTANCE(GEOLOCATION(opp.account.BillingLatitude, opp.account.BillingLongitude), GEOLOCATION(Latitudes, Longtitudes), 'mi');
        }
    }
}


Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void GEOLOCATION(Decimal, Decimal)


What have you tried? What research have you done? Where, precisely are you stuck?

basically lead assign near about the owner of the record so how to find the nearest location of the owner

repeating what you already have in your question isn't very helpful.

Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void GEOLOCATION(Decimal, Decimal)

The DISTANCE() and GEOLOCATION() functions you've attempted to use here are formula functions. They cannot be used in Apex.

In Apex, use the Location Class that has methods such as:
getDistance(firstLocation, secondLocation, unit)

Calculates the distance between the two specified locations,
using an approximation of the haversine formula and the specified unit.

